# What's the difference between Guatemalen, Honduran and Salvedorean Cream?

Tags: cream

All three are available at my local mexican market. How are they different?

Comment: I've wondered this too!

Comment: Where they're made, I'd guess ;) I had similar issues with sausages in the UK. Apparently every region on the island has its own style of sausage that are vastly different.

Answer (score 4):

I haven't actually had these creams (I might have to try next time I'm at a Latin grocery), but a little research indicates that Guatemalen cream is something like a hybrid of American style sour cream, and creme fraiche; Honduran cream is saltier, and Salvadoran one is sweeter.

[Here's a review.](http://marginalrevolution.com/marginalrevolution/2010/08/central-american-sour-cream-standoff.html)

Answer (score 2):

The primarily difference is where they are made.

But there's also a play on its acidity. Kind of like milk vs. buttermilk or different types of plain yogurt. I always thought of El Salvadorian crema was more acidic for my tastes. I think of Honduran as a less acidic, more creamy taste and I really enjoy it.

Answer (score 1):

I find Salvadoran cream thinner and tastes like a very mild cheese (cheddar?) And Mexican cream is like sour cream only 100 times better. It's thick, made using live cultures like how yogurt is made and had a more profound dour cream flavor. I love both. Salvadoran cream is the best imho. If they are making them in the Mexican market, you should try them!

Comment: What about Honduran or Guatemalen?

Answer (score -1):

I just recently tried crema hondureña in the home of a friend who grew up in Honduras. To me, it has a taste and texture similar to a kind of mild, creamy cheese sauce like the queso dip you might find in some Mexican restaurants. It's delicious! I haven't tried the other countries you mentioned, but I'm familiar with Mexican table cream (almost sweet, pure cream taste), and Mexican sour cream (like American only a smooth, thick liquid and much tastier).

Answer (score -3):

The Salvadoran is to my palate the most flavorful. .but really buy what you like! American sour cream is thicker....I wish I had never purchased the Salvadoran sour cream...as it is all I want now and not as readily available

Comment: "Buy what you like" - sure, but the point of the question is to find out how they differ without having to buy them all.